# PHP UTF-8 file naming (Persian name)

Tags: php

I use the following code to build folder:

```
$dir = 'فارسی';
mkdir($dir);
```

But the created folder name converted to  `ظپط§ط±ط³غŒ`

---

This problem also exists in the upload files.
I uploaded the `فارسی.jpg` but it converted to `ظپط§ط±ط³غŒ.jpg`

---

This problem only exists on the local host. (I use windows 8 - xampp)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows, the solution is to convert filename / folder name to Windows-1252 encoding:

```
$dir = 'فارسی';
$dir = iconv(mb_detect_encoding($dir, "auto"), 'Windows-1252', $string);
mkdir($dir);
```

I believe that is a reason why the error occcured on localhost and never on server:
The server probably uses Linux.